# openpyxl - how to find the max row that contains a specific string?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Let's say I have an excel spreadsheet like the example below. How can I use openpyxl check whether the last row contains the string "xyz" in column 1? For context, the end use case will be to send an email if the last row contains xyz

|  | column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc 1 | 123 |
| 2 | abc 2 | 456 |
| 3 | abc 1 | 123 |
| 4 | xyz 1 | 123 |
| 5 | xyz 2 | 456 |
| 6 | abc 1 | 123 |
| 7 | abc 2 | 456 |

```
import smtplib
import sys
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("myworkbook.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("myworksheet")

count = 0
for row in ws:
    if not all([cell.value == None for cell in row]):
        count += 1

max_row = count-1

if "xyz" in row[max_row].value:
    print("hi")
```

Edit: The max row in the previous version was not working because it always returned row 999 for some reason. With the new code, it returns the correct max row. Now the problem is with the `row[max_row].value`.  I'm getting `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType'` is not iterable, because "row" is NoneType. xyz is string and `max_row` is int, the problem is with `row`

Also removed the for loop and just ended it with print hi for simplicity, since I am not asking about the last part.

Comment: Sorry what’s the question? It looks like your code does exactly what you plan to do. What’s the current outcome, and what’s the expected outcome, and errors if any?

Comment: I'm getting this error that says TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with max_row because max_row returns an integer (just the row number).

Comment: Expected outcome is to send the email if the last row has "xyz." I haven't written the code for that part yet so right now I just have "print("hi") in place of # send email ... but that isn't working either.

Comment: Ok now we’re talking… if `max_row` is returning an integer, is it possible that it’s the row id for the last row? If so, perhaps to access the last row, all you need is `ws[ws.max_row]`, and no need for the loop.

Comment: Thank you, that was a big hint. I edited the code in the original question.

Comment: Good change! Now the next step is to read the max row from the work sheet, i.e. the variable `ws`, not from `row`. Perhaps try print out the last row, i.e. `print(ws[max_row])`, see what it is first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `row[max_row]` you are trying get `max_row`-th *column* of `row`, not last row of the worksheet. Your should point to specific column of last row of sheet, i.e. using cell function from openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.cell):

```
if 'xyz' in str(ws.cell(row=max_row, col=2).value):
    print('hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both, this is what ended up working.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("myworkbook.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("myworksheet")

count = 0
for row in ws:
    if not all([cell.value == None for cell in row]):
        count += 1

max_row = count-1    

if "xyz" in ws.cell(max_row, 2).value:
    print("hi")
```